# Working with multiple Python versions **including development header files**?

Tags: python, packaging, multiple-versions

I develop Python application with support for different Python versions. I use `pyenv` to have multiple Python versions on my system (Linux, if that matters) and to switch between them.

Now I also need to build Python packages with extensions, as not all of them yet publish wheels for the recent Python version. And my system has development headers which is guaranteed to work with only one Python version (package `python3-dev`, which, on my system, serves Python 3.10.6). So attempts to build (some) packages in e.g. Python 3.12 `pyenv` environment fail.

Ideally, I want to be able to say:

```
$ pyenv use 3.12
$ pip wheel <package>  # <-- and GCC is using headers for Python 3.12, not for the version for which the development headers are installed system-wide
```

Is this a reasonable expectation? How can it be achieved?

Comment: [Nix](https://nixos.org/) does a great job of this. Ask it for `python39.withPackages(p: [p.lxml p.yaml])` for example, and it installs (maybe compiles, if necessary) Python 3.9 with lxml and pyyaml.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use pyinstaller with pipenv / pyenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548730/how-to-use-pyinstaller-with-pipenv-pyenv)

Answer (score 1):

One option which certainly satisfies this (whether it fits your workflow is a separate question) is to use docker containers.

For python, this is relatively easy:

```bash
docker run -it python:3.10 bash
```

Drops you into a bash shell where `python` is python 3.10, gcc is installed, and the python headers are present (try `python-config --includes` to check).

To keep your changes, you can commit the container, or you can move the 'setup' to a single dockerfile and parametrize the base:

```
#syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4

ARG version=3.10
FROM python:${version}
RUN install-stuff
```

Now you can build multiple images by supplying `$version` at build time:

```bash
docker build --build-arg version=3.12 -t dev:3.12
```

Docker will pull down the relevant base container and build your image on top of it.

This is possible and easy in this case, because python provides a set of high quality docker images for every version you might care about.